Problem Transforming Server and Db name Parameter in database project Dacpac using Azure Devops release pipeline (Produces Extra bracket)
I have sql DB project created in VS 2022, In there I have a Stored procedure and I Parameterized the Server and db as it connects to different server using link server. I create a build in Azure devops and a release from that with the parameter i used in that stored Procs. When I deploy dacpack in azure devops it transforms this variable but adds extra bracket.
I  defined $(UserServerAndDB) is SQLCMD variable in my db project . My sp
USP_GetUser.sql looks like this in db project:
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_GetUser]
    @userId nvarchar(16)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT UserId, UserName
    FROM [$(UserServerAndDB)].[dbo].[User]
    WHERE UserId = @userId;
END

Now in azure devops I built the db project and I  have dacpack in artifacts. I created release pipeline from that artifact and in there I used SQL Server database deploy task to deploy my Dacpac.
It works great. However my variable which i created in release pipeline named UserServerAndDB with the value for this USER_D_LK].[User is not transorming correctly.I added it as Additional Arguments to this task /v:UserServerAndDB=$(UserServerAndDB) toSQL Server database deploy task see below

but when it finishes DB deploy
instead
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_GetUser]
    @userId nvarchar(16)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT UserId, UserName
    FROM [USER_D_LK].[User].[dbo].[User]
    WHERE UserId = @userId;
END

Any help would be much appreciated!
it creates the below and add 2 brackets. it is very strange where that extra brackets comes from
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_GetUser]
    @userId nvarchar(16)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT UserId, UserName
    FROM [USER_D_LK].[User]].[dbo].[User]
    WHERE UserId = @userId;
END


Did you try to use quoted identifiers instead? Ie. "$(UserServerAndDB)" and USER_D_LK"."User. Otherwise perhaps you can have a view that points to LS and which you create in a script which handles the above stuff

I created a SQL DB project with the similar variable and SQL script in Visual Studio 2022 on my local machine, then run the publish task in Visual Studio. I can reproduce the same issue the it has the extra brackets ']'.
Looks like, the problem is with the way that passing server name and DB name using only one variable.
To fix the issue, you can do like as below:

Define two variables, one for server name ($(ServerName)) and another for DB name ($(DBName)) in the SQL DB project.


Change the SQL script like as below.
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_GetUser]
    @userId nvarchar(16)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT UserId, UserName
    FROM [$(ServerName)].[$(DBName)].[dbo].[User]
    WHERE UserId = @userId;
END




EDIT:
You can try the "IF...ELSE" statement in your SQL script.
For example.
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_GetUser]
    @userId nvarchar(16)
AS
BEGIN
    IF '$(ServerName)' = 'xxxx'
        SELECT UserId, UserName
        FROM [$(DBName)].[dbo].[User]
        WHERE UserId = @userId;
    ELSE
        SELECT UserId, UserName
        FROM [$(ServerName)].[$(DBName)].[dbo].[User]
        WHERE UserId = @userId;
END

Use the condition "$(ServerName)' = 'xxxx" to compare the server, The 'xxxx' should be the current server where the script is running:

If on the same server, set "FROM [$(DBName)].[dbo].[User]".
If not on the same server, set "FROM [$(ServerName)].[$(DBName)].[dbo].[User]".



thank you for checking and confirming that . Your suggestion will work but the problem I have is on my DEV and UAT[$(ServerName)].[$(DBName)].[dbo].[User]
[$(ServerName)].[$(DBName)].[dbo].[User]
I have link server so this makes sense [$(ServerName)].[$(DBName)].[dbo].[User]
however on my pre prod and prod both Databases are on the same server so iI only have [$(DBName)].[dbo].[User]. This is why I used one variable to be able to control that in one variable. Any other suggestion that might work in the scenario?

Doesn't this just mean that in DEV/UAT the server variable is [Server]. and in pre/prod your server variable is simply blank. BTW Linked servers are bad and differences between environments like this is bad, but I'm sure you don't have any control over that

@user464291, You can try the "IF...ELSE" statement in your SQL script. See EDIT. Hope this can help you.

Thanks you so much for your helpful advice . However after this change I have 1more issue. My DBServiceAccount which runs Dacpack as user has dbo access to my Main DB and has read access to the link server DB. however
Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 2557, Level 16, State 7, Procedure UserDB.sys.sp_table_statistics2_rowset, Line 105 User 'Deployment_User' does not have permission to run DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS for object [UserDB].[dbo].[User]. I thought read access is enough to link server DB why does it need DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS to the tables? It doe snot make sense

@user464291, When querying on a linked server, it seems that the sp_table_statistics2_rowset is called on the linked server by design. It is used to get current query optimization statistics for a table or indexed view. The query optimizer uses statistics to estimate the cardinality or number of rows in the query result, which enables the Query Optimizer to create a high quality query plan. See the docs "DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS".

@user464291,  And this answer should be able to answer to your doubt.

thank you for all the help . i ended up creating Synonyms and for synonyms it is not adding double brackte

Just an update Actually my synonyms still experiencing the same double bracket issue unfortunately. It seems as if you drop synonyms one time and manually create them correctly next type of Dackpack has exact value for the value it will not mess it up (Maybe cashe it). But if it is new it will add 2 brackets

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_GetUser]
@userId nvarchar(16)
AS
BEGIN
IF '$(ServerName)' = 'xxxx'
SELECT UserId, UserName
FROM [$(DBName)].[dbo].[User]
WHERE UserId = @userId;
ELSE
SELECT UserId, UserName
FROM [$(ServerName)].[$(DBName)].[dbo].[User]
WHERE UserId = @userId;
END. This needs elevated access to teh link server db which is not ideal even GRANT view database state did not work

I wonder if there is any escape for special character I already tried UserServerAndDB = USER_D_LK].[User for below but no luck  CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_GetUser]
@userId nvarchar(16)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT UserId, UserName
FROM [$(UserServerAndDB)].[dbo].[User]
WHERE UserId = @userId;
END
